# getJSON and invalid label

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to get json data from a url. Url is working ok in FF. I am trying code like this

```
$.getJSON("http://testsite.com/1234/?callback=?", function(data){   
        //here i am getting invalid label error**
    }
);
```

When i am trying without callback=? i am getting empty data

```
$.getJSON("http://testsite.com/1234/", function(data){   
            //here i am data = ""
        }
    );
```

Whats going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the site you're fetching from doesn't support JSONP, with this URL:

```
http://testsite.com/1234/?callback=?
```

It's *trying* to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP), but the server is returning a plain JSON response (not wrapped in a function).

With this URL:

```
http://testsite.com/1234/
```

It's not trying JSONP at all, and being blocked by the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

---

To fetch data from a remote domain, it needs to support JSONP so it can be grabbed with a GET request, so you'll need to either add support to that domain, or proxy the request through your own.

Comment: Yes its showing only json data. But in FF the url is working ok. I need that json object to be returned in some variable.

Comment: @coure06 - The response *isn't* ok, that's the point, you're getting `{...data...}` what you *need* to get is  `functionName({...data...})`, the server isn't returning this, so you're getting an invalid label syntax error.

Comment: How to "proxy the request" through my own?

Comment: @coure06 - Yahoo has a good writeup on this: http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html